# Can anyone view the data in my firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Can anyone view the data in my firebase database if I have these properties set?

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
```

I know people can't write into them, but can they see the data?
I'm trying to see if I can make a login system.

Answer (score 1):

With `.read` set to false globally, the only way to read from the database is using a Google access token to bypass rules altogether (this is only possible for accounts with appropriate IAM permissions on the project). So no, people can't see your data.

If you're looking to make a login system, we'd strongly recommend using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) to securely manage user accounts rather than e.g. storing password hashes in the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `".read": true`, but I don't recommend it. 
It is not a safe practice to adopt.